# How to join table with already joined table?

Tags: sql

I want to connect table with lessons with table with students
Here is my query:

```
    SELECT * 
    FROM Student 
    JOIN (
        SELECT * 
        FROM Lesson 
        JOIN Has on Has.Diid = Lesson.Diid 
            and Has.Name = Lesson.Name
          ) m 
        on m.CreditBookNumber = Student.CreditBookNumber
```

But it doesn't work. Is there a way to rewrite this?

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Comment: There's nothing inherently wrong with your query.  Be more specific than "doesn't work".  Sample data might be more helpful than ERD.  I wonder whether the condition `Has.Name = Lesson.Name` is appropriate.

Comment: @DaveCosta  Here is the problem `The "Diid" column for" m " is specified more than once`

Comment: For future reference, you could edit your question to add information rather than putting it in a comment.  This error message is very helpful!  There *was* a problem with the query that I didn't see, but as soon as I see the error message it is obvious.  This is why including details is helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, I would avoid the subquery here. It's superfluous at best and could cause errors to be thrown at worst. The biggest opportunity for Error that I see is that in your subquery's result set there will be two columns with the same name `diid`. You'll need to alias those in order for them to pick up two different names and not toss an error.

Consider instead:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Student 
JOIN Has ON
    Student.CreditBookNumber = Has.CreditBookNumber
JOIN Lesson ON
     Has.Diid = Lesson.Diid 
     and Has.Name = Lesson.Name
```

If you are bound and determined to do this in a subquery then you will need to list out each column and provide an alias for columns where the name collides.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Student 
JOIN (
    SELECT Lesson.*,
        Has.Diid as HasDiid,
        Has.Name as HasName,
        Has.CreditBookNumber,
        Has.Gid
    FROM Lesson 
    JOIN Has on Has.Diid = Lesson.Diid 
        and Has.Name = Lesson.Name
      ) m 
    on m.CreditBookNumber = Student.CreditBookNumber
```

But since this much more complex sql will produce identical results as the first sql above, it's really overkill.